# Identify unnumbered bags from 11015 - with pictures

Tags: set-identification

I bought LEGO Classic 11015 set. I have 7 unnumbered bags that came with the set all other numbered bags have been completed so I'm unsure what set they are from.

[image: random bag #1]

[image: random bag #2]

Answer (score 2):

I took a sampling of the most interesting parts visible in your bags, and all are contained in the [11015](https://brickset.com/sets/11015-1/Around-the-World) set inventory in the correct amounts. Based on this I'd conclude that these simply came with the set, just not in numbered bags. This is further supported by the existence of parts like [SKI STICK 3M, W/SHAFT Ø3,2](https://brickset.com/parts/6250678/ski-stick-3m-w-shaft-%C3%B83-2), two of which are clearly visible in your photo, but none is included in any of the official models buildable from the seven numbered bags. Yet they are included in the set inventory, so they must be there for the creative play.